# Does Angular 7's material table have virtual scrolling?

Tags: angular, pagination, virtualscroll

I am beginning to suspect that I don't understand Angular's material table implementation, or the concept of virtual scrolling, or both :-)

As I understand it, virtual scrolling is a technique used to limit the number of DOM elements which need to be rendered when scrolling in a large set of data, for instance a table. We have a viewport of size N, say 5 elements, through which we "view" the table. When scrolling, the *content* of the 5 elements that we view changes, but the DOM always renders only 5 elements.

The Angular material table example from https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#pagination seems to me to be doing the same thing.

If we look at the DOM elements of that page, we selected a page size of 5, and the DOM only renders 5 rows in the table:

[image]

So my question is simple: is this virtual scroll or not?

Comment: https://shlomiassaf.github.io/table-demo/table-demo#/

Comment: The rendering of DOM in the table is very similar to that of a virtual scrolling, the difference is their controls. Table render data through pagination where you can jump to particular page to view data whereas virtual scroll just let you render data in a linear fashion. These controls has a different purpose.

Comment: To answer your question it doesn't have a virtual scrolling

Comment: @Roel Thanks for your comment -- to be honest, I still don't understand the difference. Why is the Angular example *not* virtual scrolling?

Comment: Because the pagination pattern used doesn't involve scrolling at all.

Comment: @enf0rcer OK, so the difference is just the user action, i.e. scrolling vs. clicking through pages? And the low level implementation is (conceptually) similar?

Comment: Your first conclusion is correct, the second one is a little harder to say. Both the virtual scroll pattern and pagination pattern applied by the material table ensure that the DOM doesnt get overloaded with elements that are not in the visible view area. But the virtual scroll pattern is a lot more complex in terms of technology compared to the used pagination pattern. So I would say at the low level implementation, they are not similar at all, but they do share a similar purpose.

Comment: One thing about your first conclusion, please do note that scrolling itself isn't "virtual scrolling". Thats only the case when the DOM gets cleaned and populated based on the  current position of the scroll area. Another pattern that might look similar, but is completely different is the infinite scrolling pattern. That pattern doesnt clean the DOM, but it does populate the DOM when you scroll down.

Comment: @enf0rcer Thanks! Today, I realised I had not thought deeply about scrolling before :-)
So, roughly speaking, we have three approaches:
1) scrolling = DOM renders all the data, and I move around in it
2) virtual scrolling = DOM renders only the selected subset based on my position  and repopulates those elements as I scroll up and down
3) infinite scrolling = keeps populating the DOM as I scroll down.

Comment: @Cristina that's correct!